# Dynamic Allocation of Structure variable

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, structure

Following is the method of dynamic memory allocation I learnt ,

```
int *p = new int;
```

i.e.

```
pointer-variable = new data-type;
```

However in another programme of linked list, I saw a structure delaration

```
struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *next;
}
```

And declaration of its instance was like

```
struct node *temp, *s;
temp = new(struct node);
```

I mean it should be wrong because according to the syntax it should not include struct , it should be like this

```
node *temp, *s;
    temp = new node ;
```

Where am I wrong,can anyone please guide me ?

This is the [source code](https://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-single-linked-list/) ,Refer to code at line no. 125 & 126.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has nothing to do with dynamic allocation, really.

When you say `struct node { ... };` in C++, it creates two type names, `node` and `struct node`, both referring to the same type:

```
node x;
struct node y;  // x and y are variables of the same type
```

The reason for this slightly weird behavior is that C++ was based on C. In C, `struct node { ... };` only creates a single type name, `struct node`. You have to use `typedef` manually to get a shorter name that does not include `struct`:

```
typedef struct node { ... } node;  // C
```

C++ wanted to make it easier to create short type names without having to type `struct` everywhere while at the same time keeping compatibility with existing C code.

(Also, there is a common unix function called `stat`, which takes a pointer to a struct also called `stat`:

```
int stat(const char *, struct stat *);
```

Here `struct stat` unambiguously refers to the type, not the function. C++ had to support this syntax to be able to call `stat`.)

Your code is written in a weird C-like style (which includes the `struct` keyword everywhere), but `new` does not exist in C, so it cannot have been actual C.

Answer (score -1):

```
node *temp, *s;
temp = new node ;
```

This is the syntax for dynamic memory allocation in C++

However,

```
struct node *temp, *s;
temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

This is the syntax used in C
 In C, the keyword 'struct' has to be written before the structure name.

keyword 'new' is not there in C.

Comment: `new` does not exist in C.

Comment: The site where I looked stated it as c++ code. Link is here https://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-single-linked-list/    Please see the code at line 125 & 126

Comment: `temp = malloc (sizeof *temp)` for C.

Comment: @Brijesh That code is pretty bad. There's a class that's not really a class (`single_llist` contains no member variables; it's really just a collection of functions that use a global variable), broken memory allocation checks (`temp = new ...; if (temp == NULL)`, but `new` cannot return `NULL`), and many other issues.

Comment: @melpomene, Sir I am new to programming & I don't know much, I am just combing the web to learn from any site  where I can get content. I don't have much resource to determine how efficient the code is.

Comment: @Brijesh I haven't even mentioned efficiency. "Just combing the web" is not a good way to learn; it means you'll also learn lots of bad habits and even incorrect code that you'll have to unlearn later. There's a [C++ book guide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1848654) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

//USE THE CODE LIKE THIS.....

```
struct node *temp, *s;
temp = (struct node*) new(struct node);
```

// as temp is a struct node pointer so we need to typecast it before assigning..

Comment: That makes no sense. What do you think typecasts are for?